# HTML escape codes and differences between W3C HTML4 and HTML5 validator

Tags: html

The [W3C HTML 4 fragment validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) accepts this code:

```
<a href='http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=+PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A+SELECT+%3FAgent%0D%0A+FROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2012%2FpyRdfa%2Fextract%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fontomatica.com%2Fpublic%2Ftest%2F2_infotext.html%3E%0D%0A+WHERE%0D%0A+{%0D%0A+%3Fs+foaf%3AAgent+%3FAgent+.%0D%0A+}%0D%0A&amp;default-graph-uri=&amp;output=text&amp;stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl' title='Click here to query the page using SPARQL'><img src='http://www.example.com/public/bin/logo_sparql.png' alt='Run SPARQL query'/></a>
```

When the same code is in a document submitted to the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) using the HTML5 template, it reports:

```
 Bad value for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
```

at the location `SPARQL'><img`

To my eye there is no char that must be escaped (e.g. a pipe char).

What do I change so the element  is accepted by the HTML5 validator?

Comment: Your curly brackets `{` might need to be encoded as `%7B`.

Comment: correctomundo Brad! (apologies to Pulp Fiction aficionados). Please answer so I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you escape `{` and `}` as `%7B` and `%7D`, it works.

```
<a href='http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=+PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A+SELECT+%3FAgent%0D%0A+FROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2012%2FpyRdfa%2Fextract%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fontomatica.com%2Fpublic%2Ftest%2F2_infotext.html%3E%0D%0A+WHERE%0D%0A+%7B%0D%0A+%3Fs+foaf%3AAgent+%3FAgent+.%0D%0A+%7B%0D%0A&amp;default-graph-uri=&amp;output=text&amp;stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl' title='Click here to query the page using SPARQL'><img src='http://www.example.com/public/bin/logo_sparql.png' alt='Run SPARQL query'/></a>
```